# SQL left outer join to a min value of right table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables, lets say `table1` and `table2`.

```
 table1 || table2
--------||-------------
 col1   || col1 | col2 
--------||------|------
 a      || a    | 4    
 b      || a    | 2    
 c      || a    | 5    
 d      || b    | 1
        || b    | 3
        || d    | 6
```

With `SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2 FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.col1` I get following:

```
 table1.col1 | table2.col2
-------------|-------------
 a           | 4           
 a           | 2           
 a           | 5           
 b           | 1           
 b           | 3           
 c           | NULL           
 d           | 6
```

How is it possible to achieve this (only get the minimum of `table2.col2` so that there's no entry of `table1.col1` more than once):

```
 table1.col1 | table2.col2
-------------|-------------
 a           | 2           
 b           | 1           
 c           | NULL           
 d           | 6
```

Or is it a wrong approach?

Comment: use **group by** and **min**

Comment: MySQL and/or SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solution, use a correlated sub-query:

```
select col1, (select min(col2) from table2 t2 where t2.col1 = t1.col1)
from table1 t1
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `MIN`:

```
SELECT
    t1.col1,
    MIN(t2.col2) AS col2
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
GROUP BY t1.col1
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/2545/0)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but always got this message: "Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause".

Comment: @gummiflummi You must be selecting more columns. In that case, put the other columns in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Or try a correlated sub-query. May be easier to handle when lots of columns.

Comment: @jarlh: Thank's, I'll take a look at this. (I have lots of columns)!

Answer (score 0):

If there are more columns in `table2` you may want to use `APPLY` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table2 
            WHERE table1.col1 = table2.col1 ORDER BY table2.col2)oa
```